# Integrating $\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2k}e^{-ax^2}\, dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2k}e^{-ax^2}\, dx}$$
I know this integral can be computed by [taking successive derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556525/what-is-the-proper-method-to-integrate-x2e-ax2) using the known integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-ax^2}\, dx}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ :

What other ways exist to evaluate this? I tried :

$$\begin{align}f(a)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2k}e^{-ax^2}\, dx}\\f'(a)&=-\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2k+2}e^{-ax^2}\, dx}\end{align}$$
Now integrating by parts, ($x^{2k+1}$ and $xe^{-ax^2}$) like :

$$\begin{align}f'(a)&=\left[-\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2a}e^{-ax^2}\right]_{0}^{\infty}-\frac{2k+1}{2a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2k}e^{-ax^2}\, dx}\\f'(a)&=-\frac{2k+1}{2a}f(a)\end{align}$$

That makes $\large f(a)=Ca^{-k-\frac{1}{2}}$, ([checked here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=f%27%28a%29%3D-%282k%2B1%29%2F%282a%29f%28a%29)) but this disagrees with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190759/to-show-int-infty-infty-x2ne-x2dx-2n-sqrt-pi-4nn) and I have no way of finding $C$ either.

So, can this integral only be computed with by differentiation, or is something else wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure $f'(a)$ is correct?

Comment: That's a specious solution of your ODE, since $f$ is a function of $a$, not $x$.

Comment: @J.G. Thanks, just mistyped it into wolfram. I will update the question

Comment: Your solution is not correct. It should be $$f(a) = C. a^{-\left( k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
and perhaps 
$$C = (2k)!{\sqrt{\pi}}/4^kk!$$

Comment: This differentiation-under-the-integral approach is just a more convoluted way to reach $$f(a)=\int_0^\infty x^{2k}e^{-ax^2}\,dx\stackrel{t=x\sqrt a}=\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{2k}}{a^k}e^{-t^2}\frac{dt}{\sqrt a}=f(1)a^{-(k+1/2)}$$ and we don't get any new information on $f(1)$.

Comment: This is just the gamma function, values are not known at all the values ...

Comment: @NN2 does this mean that (by $f(1)$)? $$C = \int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{2k}e^{-x^2}\, dx} $$

Comment: @AnthonyML I’m pretty sure about that. It cannot be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the "standard trick" (using polar coordinates) can be extended to handle this case as well.
$$
\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}dx\cdot\int e^{-ay^2}dy=\iint x^2 e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\iint (x^2+y^2) e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}dxdy,
$$
where the second equality is by symmetry; so
$$
\int x^2 e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{\iint(x^2+y^2)e^{-a(x^2+y^2)}dxdy}{2\int e^{-ax^2}dx}.
$$
The double integral can be evaluated in polar coordinates, and of course the denominator is known.  This approach can be used to solve $\int x^k e^{-ax^2}$ for any even $k$.